# Error when trying to create a topic on Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to create a kafka topic using

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic testing
```

but the following error is reported:

```
Error while executing topic command : Not all brokers have rack information. Add --disable-rack-aware in command line to make replica assignment without rack information.
[2018-01-23 15:03:44,471] ERROR kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: Not all brokers have rack information. Add --disable-rack-aware in command line to make replica assignment without rack information.
    at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.getBrokerMetadatas(AdminUtils.scala:443)
    at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:461)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:110)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:63)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

Both `zookeeper`

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/zookeeper.properties
```

and `kafka-server`

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties
```

have been successfully started.

Addition of `--disable-rack-aware` will solve this issue but how can I make replica assignment with rack information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess not all of your brokers have a rack configuration. Grep your server.properties for the key `broker.rack`. If this appears only in some but not all of your server configurations this is the cause of your problem.

Here you can find some more details about kafka's rack awareness: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/71458/can-anyone-explain-kafka-rack-awareness-feature.html

Answer (score 0):

When you configure some brokers with `broker.rack` and let others without `broker.rack`, that will generate a error (exactly what you got) when you create a manuel topic on your cluster (Automatic topic creation ignore the rack information).

To fix this issue:

**Option 1**: place the property `broker.rack=null` on all brokers.

**Option 2**: edit the property `broker.rack` on all brokers where is missing, will the id of the rack.

**Option 3**: add the property `--disable-rack-aware` to your kafka-topics command.

For more details about rack awareness, Here is the [kafka documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/post-deployment.html#balancing-replicas-across-racks)