# Kafka rack awareness feature

Tags: apache-kafka

Is kafka rack awareness activated by default on my cluster? 
If I configure some brokers with the broker.rack and let other brokers without broker.rack, does 
kafka rack awareness affect my cluster?

Comment: I'm pretty sure all brokers need the setting for it to work the best

Comment: Can somebody point to me to some tutorial/documentation of what is a rack? Is it same as broker?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer I get after some research:

When you configure some brokers with `broker.rack` and let others without `broker.rack`, Manual Topic creation will fail and generate an error (Automatic topic creation ignore the rack information).

To fix this issue:

**Option 1**: place the property `broker.rack=null` on all brokers.

**Option 2**: edit the property `broker.rack` on all brokers where is missing, will the id of the rack.

**Option 3**: add the property `--disable-rack-aware` to your kafka-topics command.

For more details about rack awareness, Here is the [kafka confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/post-deployment.html#balancing-replicas-across-racks)

Answer (score 1):

Default value of broker.rack is null. So if you define broker.rack for some brokers Kafka will have two options for replication assignment (your_rack_id and null). So I guess there is no reason to NOT consider these two options during assignment.

Answer (score 1):

As for your question, it won't affect your Kafka cluster.

Each broker has its own configuration file. So, if u are adding the `broker.rack` configuration on one broker and not on other it won't cause any harm to the cluster.
But for best practices, if you want to have a fault-tolerant system and that your data should not be lost from other leader partition on different broker then you have to apply the configuration on all the brokers.

For more knowledge on rack awareness and replication go through the Kafka docs: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_racks

Comment: I found this question that talk about a issue when creating a Topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402577/error-when-trying-to-create-a-topic-on-apache-kafka

Answer (score 0):

I tried this scenario(where some brokers have **broker.rack** property set and others don't have). Topic creation is failing with below error:

```
Error: Not all brokers have rack information for replica rack aware assignment. - Unknown broker error (unknown)
```